# how to enable xpack.security.enabled?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch 7, on Ubuntu. I believe X-Pack is installed by default, but I need to enable it.

In which file should I set this setting?

My cluster settings are in: `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and `/etc/default/elasticsearch`, but I cannot see `xpack.security.enabled` in either of files...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

write the following line in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml :

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

when you enable xpack.security, you need to create user and password unless you cannot use elasticsearch or kibana. follow this guide:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/get-started-enable-security.html

Comment: In addition to the above answer. You also need a valid license.